# Can't INSERT data into mysql from form using php-(codeigniter)

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am a beginner at Codeigniter.How to store the form values in mysql using codeigniter ,Can any one help me. I've tried to do the same here Click here. But when i run and fill the form i get error 404 .Thanks in advance .This is the code:

mysql code:

```
   CREATE TABLE `meal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(50,0) NOT NULL,
  `description` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

model:

```
<?php
class insert_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
function form_insert($data){
// Inserting in Table(meal) of Database(cl36-smart)
$this->db->insert('meal', $data);
 }
 }
?>
```

view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>  


<title>Add Meal</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<?php echo form_open('site'); ?>
   <h2> add meal by filling the brackets  bellow  </h2>
   <?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
   <CENTER><h3 style="color:green;">Data inserted successfully</h3></CENTER>   <br>
```

```
<?php echo form_label('Meal Name:');?><br/> 
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name'));  ?><br>
<?php echo form_label('Unit Price:');?><br/>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'unit_price', 'name' => 'unit_price'));    ?><br/>    
<?php echo form_label('Description:');?><br/>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'description', 'name' => 'description')); ?><br/>
<?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Add')); ?><br/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>


</div>


</body>


</html>
```

controller:

```
 <?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('insert_model');
$this->load->helper( array( 'form' ) );

}

   public function index(){


    $this->load->view('view_form');
   $data = array(
 'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
 'unit_price' => $this->input->post('unit_price'),
 'description' => $this->input->post('description')    
  );
   $this->load->view('view_form', $data);

   $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
   $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';



   }

 }
```

Comment: Make class name ucfirst i.e. `Insert_model`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything is fine, only the position of some sentences are wrong in you rcontroller

from

```
 public function index(){
    $this->load->view('view_form');

    $data = array(
                  'name'        => $this->input->post('name'),
                  'unit_price'  => $this->input->post('unit_price'),
                  'description' => $this->input->post('description')    
                 );

   $this->load->view('view_form', $data);

   $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
   $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
 }
```

to
     public function index(){
        $this->load->view('view_form');

```
    $data = array(
                  'name'        => $this->input->post('name'),
                  'unit_price'  => $this->input->post('unit_price'),
                  'description' => $this->input->post('description')    
                 );

   $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
   $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';    

   $this->load->view('view_form', $data);
 }
```

you need to call the view at the end if not, the model never be called.

Comment: i get this error :Error Number: 1048

Column 'name' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `meal` (`name`, `unit_price`, `description`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/ci/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691 @elddenmedio

Comment: @ShathaKt Hi, this error is because the inputs in form have different name called in the controlled, can you check that with inspect element?

Comment: Hi, i can´t undestand why you have a call view twice, one starting the index method and second at the end, you only have one, the second one. Try it

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

first of all go into application->config->database.php in this file if you have set mysql then remove it and use **mysqli**

in your model constructor you have to add  $this->load->database();